# Modify ADW Android launcher?

Tags: android

I want to change and modify the open-source ADW launcher. The launcher is available here: 
https://github.com/AnderWeb/android_packages_apps_Launcher/

When I open the launcher code in Eclipse (File>New Android Project>From Existing Source), there are several errors and I can't actually run the project on an emulator. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: There are a whole bunch of errors in files in the src/ directory. They are usually of this form:

Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setChecked(boolean) of type QuickActionItem must 
  override a superclass method
 - Method breakpoint:QuickActionItem [entry] - setChecked(boolean)
 - implements android.widget.Checkable.setChecked

Comment: nevermind, solution here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1678122%2Fmust-override-a-superclass-method-errors-after-importing-a-project-into-eclipse&rct=j&q=%20The%20method%20of%20type%20QuickActionItem%20must%20override%20a%20superclass&ei=Oy_jTbDxHIyzrAf00vGsBg&usg=AFQjCNE4mBYR2rwYwhYi7U58KO0aGe9DEA&cad=rja

Comment: What was the solution in the end? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: $au_889 I have no idea how that solved your problem...it made no difference to the ADW source I have.