# ADW launcher source error

Tags: android

I am trying to build the ADW Launcher in Eclipse that I downloaded from:

https://github.com/AnderWeb/android_packages_apps_Launcher

When I load this project into Eclipse,a lot of errors come up, examples:

```
com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable 
firstInstallTime cannot be resolved or is not a field   
android.os.SystemProperties cannot be resolved to a type    
mContext cannot be resolved to a variable
```

..............and about 50 more

This question has been asked before here: 
[Modify ADW Android launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172612/modify-adw-android-launcher)
, but does not a clear answer

Ca someone please provide with clear instructions on how to fix this?

Comment: did you import android.R? also do you any errors in your resources files?

Comment: importing doesnt help........and no errors in res......they are only in src

Comment: i am not asking you to import. i am asking if you have this statement `import android.R`.

Comment: just checked..........no